# Facebook Graph API subscription to /pages/conversations does not update on outgoing messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with Facebook pages and building an app that allows you to send/receive private messages for your page from an external app.

Everything works fine, I can import old messages, send new one. My issue comes from the real time update subscription.

As explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/subscriptions), I have subscribed to the *conversations* field on the *page* object. I also set up my server to receive Facebook verification and the updates.

I do receive updates when someone sends a new message to my test page ( even if it's a bit slow ~30 sec delay ) but I never receive any updates when the page replies to a message.

Is there something else I need to subscribe to in order to receive these updates ? Do I need to look for another way to do it ? Or is it just not supported by Facebook real time API updates ?

Any help appreciated, let me know if you need more info and have a nice day.

Comment: I think this is by design. I'd suggest you open a bug report with Facebook to let them clarify what the desired behavior is.

Comment: Here is the link to the issue : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/845663685511396/